# Using node modules without TypeScript type definition files in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, typescript-typings

In order to use jQuery from my Angular 2 typescript components , I have followed below steps and was able to use it
succesfully.

```
//1. Install jQuery node module
npm install jquery --save

//2. Install typings
npm install typings -g

//3. Download jquery.d.ts    
typings install dt~jquery --global --save

//4. Adding main files in systemjs.config.js [ I am using systemjs and not webpack ]
'jquery':  'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js' 

//5 and then import in my component ts file
 import "jquery";
```

Now I would like to use block-ui node module in my component , for which I am not able to find d.ts file .

How can I use such a module in typescript  which does not have type script defination file.

let me know if I need to provide more information.

Comment: You can create your own definition file.

Comment: What about [this definition?](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jquery.blockUI.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped/0.0.4)

Comment: @DanielB , since it is nuget , can it be only used in MS applications ?

Comment: No, you can still download it and unpack it with like a .zip.

Comment: Don't use `typings`, use npm hosted `@types` instead. Instead of `typings install`, do `npm install --save-dev @types/jquery`. This is now favored over typings.